# Trouble using parent::* axes in selenium web driver

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to use a wildcard to navigate up the DOM in selenium, using something like this...

```
    ArrayList<WebElement> list = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'div_text')]/parent::*]"));
```

to try to get all the parent elements of the div that has 'div_text'.  This only seems to return the immediate parent, not ALL the parents.  I need to go a variable number of nodes up the DOM.

Once I get the list, I plan to iterate through with

```
for(WebElement e: list)
   if(e.getTagName().equals("table") && e.getAttribute("class").equals("blah")
       e.click();
```

Agreed that this is not the most efficient approach, but more complex xpath expressions like

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[text()='title']/[name(parent::*) = 'table'"));
```

do not seem to work in web driver.

Thanks for any insight on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, what you want is ancestor not parent.

> [XPath Axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp)
>
> ancestor: Selects all ancestors (parent, grandparent, etc.) of the current node parent
> parent: Selects the parent of the current node

Try `//div[text()='title']/ancestor::table` for table ancestors

Comment: Great, thanks so much.  I just added the table attributes I was looking for and it worked perfectly.     //div[contains(text(),'fake')]/ancestor::table[@class='today-group-header']

Comment: would do so, but don't have the reputation yet.  Appreciated none the less.

Answer (score 0):

There only is one parent element. You're probably looking for *ancestors*:

```
//div[contains(text(),'div_text')]/ancestor::*
```

The query which is not working has a syntax error, you're applying a predicate on an imcomplete axies step (...`/[name(parent::*)`..., the node or a `*` is missing).